# Why can't a deriving class override a property in its base class with a type derived from the original type?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, overriding

Effectively, I'd like to understand why this is not possible in C#:

```
class Foo{
    public Bar Property {get;set;}
}

class Boo : Foo{
    public override Baz Property {get;set;}
}

class Bar{
    //some internal stuff
}

class Baz : Bar{
    //more stuff
}
```

To me, it seems like this would have pretty clearly defined behavior in most cases, so long as the Baz class doesn't hide a member from the Bar class (with new or something). The compiler would know if this was going to happen though, so it seems like a kind of non-issue.

I also understand that this can be achieved with abstract classes, but I specifically would like to get a better understanding of why this is disallowed in the case of non-abstract classes.

Comment: This isn't allowed any more with abstract classes than it is with regular classes. Perhaps you're thinking of generic classes?

Comment: The duplicate question has an answer which demonstrates a workaround, but it doesn't answer the OP's question of "WHY is this not allowed?"

Comment: [Related GitHub Issue](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/2844)

Comment: Reading the issue, it seems to be [proposed for C# 9](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns.md).

Comment: @John But not for properties with setters.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It wouldn't make sense to allow it for property setters since you couldn't ensure type safety.

Comment: @John Exactly. I only mention because the properties in the question have setters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine someone uses your code:

```
Foo f = new Boo();
```

As the reference is of type `Foo` we can only assume `Property` to be of type `Bar`. So we can also write this now:

```
f.Property = new Boz(); // assuming Boz also derives from Bar
```

which will pretty sure not be what you actually wanted.

Comment: Yeah thanks that makes sense. I can't help but think there should be some way around it, in terms of compiler errors or something, but thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following workaround for that, but making `Foo` generic interface and implement it in `Boo` class

```cs
interface IFoo<T> where T : Bar
{
    public T Property { get; set; }
}

class Boo : IFoo<Baz>
{
    public Baz Property { get; set; }
}
```

There is also a [covariant return types](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns.md), planned in C# 9. But it'll work with readonly properties only